# Best way for call u-sql script from api/app ( like rest api, wpf app)

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want create api or desktop application that allow user to execute my u-sql script, that works on specifict Azure Data Lake Store from my Azure Account. I readed something about Azure Data Factory Service, but is there any another way in .NET to execute U-SQL script on Azure Data Lake Store Data ( and pass parameteres to this scripts ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA) .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-get-started-net-sdk) to automate actions related to your ADLA account, jobs, or catalog items. You could use this alongside the [Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk) to automate actions related to your ADLS account or file system.

Currently, passing parameters to these scripts would involve modifying the script before submitting the job, replacing values or adjusting variables as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Parameter-passing:

You can prepend your parameters by using the following statement:

```
DECLARE @parameter type = value;
```

If you want to default a script parameter in your script, you can use

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL @parameter type = default_value;
```

This will give you a default value if you do not add the explicit `DECLARE` and will be overwritten by the previous `DECLARE` statement if present.

Please visit http://aka.ms/adlfeedback to file/vote on a request to expose an SDK parameter model.